# Why does my Exception program keep running?

Tags: java, exception, while-loop, do-while

I have a program, but the problem is it keeps running even after I tell it to stop. I have told it to stop running when the Boolean variable becomes false, but even after the variable becomes false, the program keeps running. The only way I found the program to keep running is when I take out the "=true" part in the while statement. So why do I need to take out the "=true" part in the statement for the program to function normally?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EvenOdd {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        int num;
        boolean continueLoop=true;
        do {
            try {
                System.out.println("Enter an even number");
                num=input.nextInt();
                if(num%2==0)
                 System.out.println("That is an even number");
                else
                 throw new IllegalArgumentException();
                continueLoop=false;
            }
            catch(IllegalArgumentException ae) {
                System.err.println(ae+"\nThat is a odd number");
            }
        } while(continueLoop=true);
        input.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: `continueLoop=true` is an assignment, you allways set the variabe to true in that line. Looking up a basic java tutorial would have told you that: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Comment: And removing `= true`is the appropriate fix. Comparing `someBoolean == true`is redundant. Using just `someBoolean` is sufficient.

Comment: carefully review this:  while(continueLoop=true);

Comment: Your error is on this line--->  
while(continueLoop==true);
    input.close();
    }

Answer (score 0):

As the condition for the while loop you are using an assignment instead of a comparison.

When you use `continueLoop=true`, value `true` is assigned to `continueLoop` and the loop simply becomes `while(true)`; which is an infinite loop.

Use `while(continueLoop == true)` which is the comparison instead of an assignment.